# How can I improve my UK visitor visa application after one time refusal?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, tourist-visas, standard-visitor-visas

I have recently been refused a general visitor visa to the UK to travel there for 15 days and am planning to reapply soon, if possible. By the way, I am from Vietnam. 
In my application I stated that: 
1. I was a student 
  - I provided a letter from my school detailing the status of my study and the duration I have asked to take leave for the visit. 
2. I have a part time job that pays me around 231GBP per month. 
  - I provided a letter from my employer to explain my work, note my rate of monthly income (231GBP) and the duration of leave I could take from work 
  - Payment slips of the past 6 months' salary 
3. I am visiting a friend who's a student in the UK 
  - I include a letter of invitation from my friend 
  - Her university's letter of proof of student status 
  - Her BRP card and Passport info 
4. My father is paying for my visit. 
  - I include his bank statement of the past 6 months. My friend lives in London, so an amount of 1,300GBP is generally expected for a month's living expenses in London. My father's bank statement averages about 3,000GBP per month. 
  - His letter of confirmation of support whereby he stated that a fund of 8,000GBP has been put aside for my trip, plus a further credit card account of 3,000GBP. 
  - Proves of his sources of income and copy of his passport

My visa application was refused with a message as thus:

I have considered your application in the context of your evidenced personal circumstances and funding. You have declared in your visa application form that you are a working student earning GBP231 per month, and that you are single with no dependent children. You also state that you intend to visit a friend in the United Kingdom for a period of 15 days. You go on to state that your parents will meet the costs of your intended visit. However: 
* Whilst it is acknowledged that you have stated that your parents will fund your visit, and whilst your working student status has also been noted, it is reasonable to expect to see evidence of your own circumstances in your country of origin, for example, evidence to show how you are financially supported during your studies or any monies that are remitted to you on a regular basis. In support of your application you have submitted a letter from your employer regarding your employment, however, you have not submitted any documentation regarding your stated income, or any funds to which you personally have access. In addition, I am not satisfied from the documentation submitted that you would be able to afford to fund this visit without third party financial assisstance. Taken in the round, I am not satisfied that you have demonstrated that your personal circumstances are such that you would have sufficient intention to leave the UK at the end of your visit as stated. 
In light of all the above, I am not satisfied that you have demonstrated that you are a genuine visitor and will leave the UK at the end of your visit. Your application has therefore been refused under paragraphs V4.2 (a) and (c) of the Immigration Rules. 
------ 
A few points that I noted are that: 
1. I did provide proof of my income with my employer in the form of the 6 months pay slips. I am not sure why the officer stated they did not have my documentation regarding my stated income. 
2. I am a student. It is customarily in Vietnam for parents to pay for their children's education through college (and sometimes beyond). I am living with my parents (also a normal custom in Vietnam). This I also provided a copy of my household registry as proof. I am not sure how to explain this to the officer and what proofs I should be submitting for this. 
3. I don't understand why it was stated in my refusal that I wouldn't be able to fund my visit without third party financial assistance when I have included financial support information from my father and this was not questioned by the officer. 
4. Does the fact that I am a student hamper my chance of traveling, as I might be perceived to be free of any strong tie to my hometown? If so, how can I demonstrate a stronger tie with my country?  
Thank you guys very much in advance.

Comment: Did you include your own bank statements with the application?

Comment: Thank you Zach Lipton for replying. I didn't include my own bank statement as my account does not have the amount of money needed for the London standard of living. Now that you pointed this out, I think I made a mistake in thinking that only my father's account statement was necessary.